VBA code to capture cell values onto another worksheet
I have an excel template for an approval process.
What I would like to do is populate a row on another worksheet as certain cells within the template are populated, creating a report I can use to track and monitor the document and associated follow ups.
I envision it working as per the following;
Template is opened.
As user selects the values for C1, C2, C3, K2, K3, K4 (Dynamic dropdown selections) the same information/values are added to the next available row in 'Log' worksheet which is within a different workbook ("Rec Report Log"), populating columns B - G. Column A is used for a reference number.
The template itself is a read only document for users, which is why the log exists outside of the template workbook.

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

How do I ask a good question?
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
